# Gaussian filter reads same value multiple time usin BMP image

Tags: c++, image, bmp

I need to translate GaussianFilter that uses openCV to code that uses BMP image ( so i first read image, and translate it to greyscale). My function using openCV looks like ( basic GaussianFilter ) :

```
Mat CreateGaussFilter(int kernalHeight, int kernalWidth, double kernalArray[5][5]){

    Mat image = imread("konik.jpg");
    Mat grayScaleImage(image.size(),CV_8UC1);
    Mat filter(image.size(),CV_8UC1);
    cvtColor(image,grayScaleImage,CV_RGB2GRAY);

    int rows=image.rows;
    int cols=image.cols;


    int verticleImageBound=(kernalHeight-1)/2;
    int horizontalImageBound=(kernalWidth-1)/2;

    for(int row=0+verticleImageBound;row<rows-verticleImageBound;row++){
        for(int col=0+horizontalImageBound;col<cols-horizontalImageBound;col++){

            float value=0.0;

            for(int kRow=0;kRow<kernalHeight;kRow++){
                for(int kCol=0;kCol<kernalWidth;kCol++){
                    float pixel=grayScaleImage.at<uchar>(kRow+row-verticleImageBound,kCol+col-horizontalImageBound)*kernalArray[kRow][kCol];
                    value+=pixel;
                }
            }

            filter.at<uchar>(row,col)=cvRound(value);
        }      
    }
    return filter;
}
```

Now for BMP image:

i have loaded it using:

```
struct Info{
    int width;
    int height;
    int offset;
    unsigned char * info;
    unsigned char * data;

    int size;
};

Info readBMP(char* filename)
{
    int i;
    std::ifstream is(filename, std::ifstream::binary);
    is.seekg(0, is.end);
    i = is.tellg();
    is.seekg(0);
    unsigned char *info = new unsigned char[i];
    is.read((char *)info,i);

    int width = *(int*)&info[18];
    int height = *(int*)&info[22];
    int offset = *(int*)&info[10];

    unsigned char a[offset];
    unsigned char *b = new unsigned char[i - offset];
    std::copy(info,
              info + offset,
              a);

    std::copy(info + offset,
              info + i,
              b + 0);

    Info dat;
    dat.width = width;
    dat.height = height;
    dat.offset = offset;
    dat.size = i;
    dat.info = new unsigned char[offset - 1];
    dat.data = new unsigned char[i - offset + 1];

    for( int j = 0; j < offset ; j++ ){
        dat.info[j] = a[j];
    }

    for( int j = 0; j < i - offset; j++ ){
        dat.data[j] = b[j];
    }
    return dat;

}
```

turned it into grayscale usin:

```
void greyScale( unsigned char * src , int rows, int cols){
    for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for( int j = 0;  j < cols; j++){
            unsigned char r = src[3 * (i * cols + j)];
            unsigned char g = src[3 * (i * cols + j) + 1];
            unsigned char b = src[3 * (i * cols + j) + 2];

            char linearIntensity = (char)(0.2126f * r + 0.7512f * g + 0);

            src[3 * (i * cols + j)] = linearIntensity;
            src[3 * (i * cols + j) + 1] = linearIntensity;
            src[3 * (i * cols + j) + 2] = linearIntensity;
        }
    }
}
```

And now i am trying to use GaussianFilter ( translated from my OpenCV function )

```
void FilterCreation(double GKernel[][5]) {
    // intialising standard deviation to 1.0
    double sigma = 1.0;
    double r, s = 2.0 * sigma * sigma;

    // sum is for normalization
    double sum = 0.0;

    // generating 5x5 kernel
    for (int x = -2; x <= 2; x++) {
        for (int y = -2; y <= 2; y++) {
            r = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            GKernel[x + 2][y + 2] = (exp(-(r * r) / s)) / (M_PI * s);
            sum += GKernel[x + 2][y + 2];
        }
    }

    // normalising the Kernel
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            GKernel[i][j] /= sum;
}

    unsigned char ** CreateGaussFilter(unsigned char ** src,int kernalHeight, int kernalWidth, double kernalArray[5][5], int rows, int cols){
        int verticleImageBound=(kernalHeight-1)/2;
        int horizontalImageBound=(kernalWidth-1)/2;

        unsigned char ** dst = new unsigned char *[rows];
        for( int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
            dst[i] = new unsigned char [cols];
        }

        for(int row=0+verticleImageBound;row<rows-verticleImageBound;row++){
            for(int col=0+horizontalImageBound;col<cols-horizontalImageBound;col++){

                float  value=0;

                for(int kRow=0;kRow<kernalHeight;kRow++){
                    for(int kCol=0;kCol<kernalWidth;kCol++){
                        float pixel =src[kRow+row-verticleImageBound][kCol+col-horizontalImageBound]*kernalArray[kRow][kCol];
                        value+=pixel;
                    }
                }

                dst[row][col] = round(value);
            }
        }
        return dst;
    }
```

Since grayscale values are same for every channel, istead of doing calculation like in grayscale  function, i turned the data into 2d array and then back into 1d array using:

```
unsigned char ** return2darray(unsigned char *src, int width, int height, int size){
    unsigned char **array = new unsigned char *[width];
    for( int i = 0; i < width; i++ ){
        array[i] = new unsigned char[height];
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < width; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < height; j++ ){
            array[i][j] = src[3 * (i * height + j)];
        }
    }
    return array;
}

unsigned char * return1darray(unsigned char **src, int width, int height, int size){
    unsigned char *array = new unsigned char[size];

    for( int i = 0; i < width; i++ ){
        for( int j = 0; j < height; j++ ){
            array[3 * (i * height + j)] = src[i][j];
            array[3 * (i * height + j) + 1] = src[i][j];
            array[3 * (i * height + j) + 2] = src[i][j];
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

And using it like:

```
    int main() {
// load img
        Info dat = readBMP("input.bmp");
// turn in into greyscale
        greyScale(dat.data,dat.width,dat.height);
// turn 1d array into 2d   
        unsigned char** arr = return2darray(dat.data,dat.width,dat.height,dat.size);

        double GKernel[5][5];
// geneate gausian filter
        FilterCreation(GKernel);
// apply gausianFilter
        unsigned char** filter = CreateGaussFilter(arr,5,5,GKernel,dat.width,dat.height,dat.size);
// convert it back into 1d array
        unsigned char* ar = return1darray(filter,dat.width,dat.height,dat.size);

        ofstream fout;
        fout.open("out.bmp", ios::binary | ios::out);
        fout.write( reinterpret_cast<char *>(dat.info), dat.offset);
        fout.write( reinterpret_cast<char *>(ar), dat.size - dat.offset );
        fout.close();
        return 0;
    }
```

But for some reason, that I cannot realize for input :

[image]

the output looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYgBh.jpg).

It seems like it reads the same values in periodes, but that would mean the original image would have the same periods because it just reads bytes from loaded image. The GreyScale function works as it should. I am not very proficient in manipulation with images ( i was using openCV all the time ) What could cause these periods? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have mixed up your `rows` and `columns` in `CreateGaussFilter`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani could u elaborate? I have tried swapping rows for cols but the result was the same

Comment: The function is defined as `CreateGaussFilter(..., int rows, int cols)`, but you are calling `CreateGaussFilter(... dat.width,dat.height,dat.size);` First, there is extra parameter `dat.size`, second, `rows` corresponds to `height`, and `cols` corresponds to `width`.